# Django Formsets rendering fields manually

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to render fields manually in django formset.

```
<select class="form-control" id="{{ line_form.label.id_for_label }}" name="{{ line_form.label.name }}">
    {% if form.label.value %}
        <option value="{{ form.label.value }}">{{ form.label.value }}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value="" selected>-</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in view.items %}
        <option value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The name of the above field is **label** but i want it to **lines-0-label**. When i add a new form in the formset the above field has the same name it should be **lines-1-label**, and should increase so on. i.e., **lines-2-label**, **lines-3-label**, **lines-4-label**, ...., **lines-101-label**.

**views.py**

```
class InvoiceCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "books/invoice_create_or_update.html"
    model = Invoice
    form_class = InvoiceForm
    formset_class = InvoiceLineFormSet
    success_url = reverse_lazy("books:invoice-list")
```

Comment: Please show your view

Comment: added views.py . @Alasdair

Comment: A `CreateView` is not designed for formsets. You might find [django-extra-views](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) useful.

Comment: Do you mean Django parse `name="{{ line_form.label.name }}"` to `name="label"` and you want `name="lines-0-label"` instead? Do you have `for` tag like `{% for line_form in lines %}` wrap around the `<select>`?